# Horizontal dropdown with hover to vertical dropdown with click on navigation bar implementation

Tags: javascript, html, flexbox

EDIT: 
Partly fixed from @anji's comment but the main issue remains by the way. When I load the page on desktop view and the resize to mobile view (below 991px), the click doesn't expand the dropdown. The bug is subtle. When I do not do any hover or click on the desktop size, the mobile version click expands dropdown but if I do any interaction like hovering over the dropdown or clicking and then resize to mobile view, the button click doesn't expand the dropdown. But click is shown registered as found from console.

---

I am trying to make a navigation bar where the horizontal version will work as usual dropping down submenus on hover but when in vertical mode (done with flex and media-query), the dropdowns will be triggered on mouse click or tap on phone screens. Also on window resize, the dropdowns will disappear when screensize is increased from mobile to laptop by chrome devtools.

So far I got this part working but the onClick event is not getting triggered. Also in the local version, It works when I reload the page in the mobile version, not when resized to. Here is the codepen I created with the code:

https://codepen.io/rpmcmurphy/pen/pMLoOE?editors=0110

Behavior expected:

- Dropdown on hover while on big screen
- Dropdown on click when on mobile
- Dropdown will disappear when resized to big screen while dropdown is open on mobile

Problem
Click event not triggering the expected behavior (on window resize and on load both) while console says click is getting noticed.

Here is the full code:

HTML-

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="menu-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li class="has-submenu">
            <a href="">
              Has submenu
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-submenu">
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    Analytics
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    Crypto
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="">
                    Call center
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
            Contracts
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
            Listings
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
            Contact lists
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">
            Others
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS-

```
    .menu-wrapper {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;

  @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    width: 220px;
    max-width: 220px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    justify-contents: space-between;
    flex-direction: row;

    @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    > li {
      flex: 1;
      position: relative;

      &.has-submenu {
        background-color: #d3d3d3;
      }

      > a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 15px;

        &:hover {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      }

      > ul {
          display: none;
          flex-direction: column;
          position: absolute;
          text-align: left;
          width: 220px;
          background-color: #f9f9f9;
          top: 100%;

          @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
            position: static;
            width: 100%;
            top: auto;

            &.drop-down {
              display: flex;
            }
          }

          li {
            flex: 1;

            a {
              display: inline-block;
              padding: 10px 15px;
            }
          }
        }

      @media only screen and (min-width: 991px) {
        &:hover {
          > ul {
            display: flex;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

JS-

```
const mq = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 991px)');

function resized() {
  if(mq.matches) {
    $('body').on('click', '.has-submenu a', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).children('.nav-submenu').toggleClass('drop-down');

      console.log('Clicked!');
    });
  }
}

resized();
$(window).resize(function() {
   resized();
   console.log('Resized!');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next() method instead of children() method in the resized function.

```
$(this).next('.nav-submenu').toggleClass('drop-down');
```

**Updated jquery code for the resizing issue:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isSmallWindow;
  checkResize();
  function checkResize(){
    isSmallWindow = $(this).width() <= 991;
  }
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        checkResize();
    });

    $('.has-submenu a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (isSmallWindow){
          $(this).next('.nav-submenu').toggleClass('drop-down');

          console.log('Clicked!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How did I miss that! Thanks.

Comment: The main issue remains by the way. When I load the page on desktop view and the resize to mobile view (below 991px), the click doesn't expand the dropdown. That's the main issue. My mistake, I thought it started working. So apparently, resize part of the JS is not acting accordingly.

Comment: @RPMcMurphy I have updated my solution. please replace your jquery code with my solution. There is some problem with on click event listener for appending it to the body element.

Comment: It works! Thanks. Could you please specify why my solution was not working? Just for understanding. Or if you could share a resource or two where I could understand why problem persisted, that would be great.

Comment: The problem with your code is at $('body').on('click', '.has-submenu a', function(e) {}); This code is appending click event multiple times on resize function.

Comment: I found that far while debugging just before you answered. Thanks a bunch.